# How do I read the node ID?

Tags: nodes

I have few articles that were deleted by accident.

Can I add these again using their nids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Node ids are unique.

But yes you can avoid this kind of issues in feature by using url alias in drupal as you can generate same URL for different node id if current node is deleted accidentally.

Documentation for URL alias https://www.drupal.org/node/120631

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot add the node with the same id as it was before before deleted.

Node ids are unique and there is no way you can have the same id for the new node.